# Get & Highlight Current Word in an NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview

OK, so this is what I want :

- We have an `NSTextView`
- Get "current" word (as an `NSRange`?), at cursor position (how could this be determined?)
- Highlight it (change its attributes)

I'm not sure how to go about this : I mean my main concern is getting current position within `NSTextView` and getting the word at point *(I know some Text plugins support that, but I'm not sure as of the original `NSTextView` implementation...)*

Is there any built-in function for that? Or, if not, any ideas?

---

**UPDATE :** *Cursor position* (SOLVED)

```
NSInteger insertionPoint = [[[myTextView selectedRanges] objectAtIndex:0] rangeValue].location;
```

Now, still trying to find a workaround for a specifying the underlying word...

Comment: I'm really curious why this question got a '-1'. Not being able to understand/answer one's question is not enough of a reason for downvoting it. Or at least a comment would be more constructive... huh?

Comment: I don't know why, either. I'm going to balance it out.

Comment: This is actually a good question. +1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
NSUInteger insertionPoint = [myTextView selectedRange].location;
NSString *string = [myTextView string];

[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:(NSRange){ 0, [string length] } options:NSStringEnumerationByWords usingBlock:^(NSString *word, NSRange wordRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
if (NSLocationInRange(insertionPoint, wordRange)) {
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = [myTextView textStorage];
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [NSColor redColor] }; // e.g.
    [textStorage addAttributes:attributes range:wordRange];
    *stop = YES;
}}];
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't do the highlighting. Appending…

Comment: Thanks a lot. **Great answer**. (I took the liberty to correct one-or-two little bits that were not working). Now one more for you : any idea how I could hook up a selector to the `NSTextView` triggered when cursor position changes? (either with the keyboard or mouse). Should I use some sort of observer?

Comment: I was going to post that I didn't test it, but then I got distracted.

Comment: Oh, we all know how easy it is to overlook a bracket or sth-like-that... No worries! ;-)

Comment: For checking for cursor-position changes, you should observe the `NSTextViewDidChangeSelectionNotification` notification, and check to make sure the length of the new selected range is 0.

Comment: Well, I'll try that right now. Thanks a lot, mate! I really appreciate it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple algorithm to find the word's boundaries (assuming that words are space-spearated):

```
NSInteger prev = insertionPoint;
NSInteger next = insertionPoint;

while([[[myTextView textStorage] string] characterAtIndex:prev] != ' ')
    prev--;

prev++;

while([[[myTextView textStorage] string] characterAtIndex:next] != ' ')
    next++;

next--;

NSRange currentWordRange = NSMakeRange(prev, next - prev + 1);
NSString *currentWord = [[[myTextView textStorage] string] substringWithRange:currentWordRange];
```